# Angularjs need ng-model update before ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I create customdirective and  want to ng-model update before ng-change fire. Currently ng-change fire before udpate ng-mdoel value below is my code.

**Main issue is coming when i change page number in dropdown list. It alert with previous value. I think ng-mdoel update after ng-change fire. but i want ng-model fire before ng-change.**

```
app.directive('bottomPagination', function () {
    var directive = {
        templateUrl: '/App/Common/directives/bottomPagination.html',
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            currentPage: '=',
            changePageSize: '&'
        }
    };
    return directive;
});

//here is html directive (/App/Common/directives/bottomPagination.html)

       <select  id="pagesizeddl" ng-model="pageSize" ng-change="changePageSize()">
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>10</option>
                            <option>20</option>
                            <option>30</option>
                        </select>

// here is my html page where i used directive


<div data-ng-controller="ProductsList as vm">
                <div data-bottom-pagination
                        data-page-size="vm.paging.pageSize"
                        data-change-page-size="vm.changePageSize()"
                         >
                    </div>
  </div>

// This is contrller
(function () {
    // Start Products List function
    var ListControllerId = 'ProductsList';
    angular.module('app').controller(ListControllerId,
        ['$scope', ListController]);

    function ListController($scope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.paging = {
            pageSize: 10
        }; 

        vm.changePageSize = changePageSize;

        function changePageSize() {
            alert(vm.paging.pageSize);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: You could just do a `$watch` on `pageSize` instead, then call `changePageSize` in that...

Comment: From the docs:
"The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model."
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

You may want to check the method you invoke with `ng-change` to see if you are trying to manually update the bound model.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Please  send me correct code. It will help me.

Comment: I'm sure it would, but it wouldn't help anyone else. Please do some research on the internet about [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) and how it works. **Try something**. Then if you have issues with what you've tried, and can't find the answer in the documentation or the hundreds of tutorials out there, come back and ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I recently had the same problem.

My best practice solution is to add a parameter in the ng-change function in your directive template. You need to add the parameter as an JSON Object!

```
<select  id="pagesizeddl" ng-model="pageSize" ng-change="changePageSize({pageSize:pageSize})">
                        <option>5</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>20</option>
                        <option>30</option>
                    </select>
```

The property "pageSize" (of the JSON Object) will be matched with the parameter of your directive function vm.changePageSize(pageSize). So it is necessary that both have the same name!

```
<div data-ng-controller="ProductsList as vm">
            <div data-bottom-pagination
                    data-page-size="vm.paging.pageSize"
                    data-change-page-size="vm.changePageSize(pageSize)"
                     >
                </div>
```

Now you only have to alter your controller function like this:

```
function changePageSize(pageSize) {
        alert(pageSize);
    }
```